# How to add a table inside a header/footer with python and python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I want to add a table of one row and three columns to my header. Any advice ?

I try with:

```py
from docx import Document

document = Document()
section = document.sections[0]
header = section.header
table = header.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)  # method not yet implemented !

document.save('test.docx')
```

But obviously doesn't work

Comment: First, you spelt "document" wrong in the third line of code. Second, I replaced the fifth line of code with `table = header.add_table(rows=1, cols= 3)`, which gave me a "missing positional argument: 'width'" error - try messing around with that?

Comment: I fixed the code. You got that error because the header's method `add_table` isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`header.add_table()` is implemented and should work. The implementation was recent (a couple months ago), so try upgrading your `python-docx` install:

```
pip install -U python-docx
```

Note that `.add_table()` takes three parameters, a row-count, a column-count, and a width, so something like this:

```
from docx.shared import Inches

table = header.add_table(1, 3, Inches(6))
```

The documentation for that method is here:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#header-and-footer-objects